# When malting barley is it necessary to remove the small roots that grow on the grains?

Tags: beer, malt, grain, barrel, barley

I'm new at making beer and I have some questions I couldn't find answers from in my beer-making book. One of them is why everyone I saw on YT tries to remove the roots that grows on the grain after the sprouting phase of the mating process?

I mean, don't they contain sugars that will turn in ethanol?

Even if they don't, why bother removing it? Are they going to ruin the brew?

And, if it is necessary, then how to remove them efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

@MikeyJY, they are called rootlets, and the main reason to remove them is that they contain tannins, and make your beer extra bitter, like in vegetal bitterness. They can also cause problems when further drying. These rootlets do not contain enzymes, starches or sugars. These are all developed in the kernels.

[Malting your own](https://byo.com/article/malting-your-own-techniques/)